# trimming the Resultset values stored in object reference upto two decimals

Tags: java, list, resultset, trim

I store resultset values in the list in following way-

```
  while(rs.next()) 
                        {
                         Comp_Mps_sext ref_drop=new Comp_Mps_sext();

                         ref_drop.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
                         ref_drop.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
                         ref_drop.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));
                         ref_drop.setP44_readback(rs.getString(4));
                         ref_drop.setP44_setvalue(rs.getString(5));
                         ref_drop.setP44_vmeset(rs.getString(6));

                         ref_jsp.add(ref_drop);


                    }
```

where Comp_Mps_sext is the Class name.What is the ebst way to trim the values in following format ##.## and then add into the arraylsit.

**EDIT-1**

ref_jsp is defined as-

```
List<Comp_Mps_sext> ref_jsp=new ArrayList<Comp_Mps_sext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want Strings, then a simple routine to format the result is:

```
private String hundreths(String in) {
  int dotAt = in.indexOf(".");
  if (dotAt < 0) // no decimal point??
    return in + ".00";
  if (dotAt + 2 < in.length())
    in += "00";
  return in.substring(0, dotAt + 2);
  }
```

Then go thru your results:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList() = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) 
  {
  Comp_Mps_sext ref_drop=new Comp_Mps_sext();
  String result = rs.getString(1)
  ref_drop.setLogtime(result);
  myArrayList.add(hundreths(result));
  ....
```

Note that this will truncate to two places, not round the value.

Comment: ,It showing an error that **The method hundreths(String) in the type Comp_Mps_sext is not applicable for the arguments (Comp_Mps_sext)**. See  my edit above

Comment: The method hundreths() just takes a String, and looks for the decimal point in it, in order to chop off anything two characters to the right of it - It does not accept a Comp_Mps_sext (whatever that is!)

Comment: Comp_Mps_sext is class object.

Comment: See my edits above .I'm not using String in List ,I'm using class object in it.

Comment: As I started to write an inner loop that goes thru each field in the result set, I realized that you are not only saving the values, but you are doing unique processing with each - in that case, there's not much simplification that can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73243/discussion-between-tiddi-rastogi-and-rick-s).